# Camel CXF Could not find endpoint/port

Tags: spring, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, endpoint

**Overview**
I created a camel route in a Spring boot project and the spring boot runs properly.

My route is as follows:

- Getting an object in JSON format from an activemq
- Transforming it to an expected format for a SOAP webservice
- Submitting transformed data to the webservice endpint

My router class is as follows:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SaleTransactionRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Produce(uri=ServiceEndpoints.TMR_WS)
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        this.getContext().setTracing(true);
        this.getContext().getProperties().put(Exchange.LOG_DEBUG_BODY_STREAMS, "true");

        log.info("SaleTransactionRoutes has just been started ...");


        JacksonDataFormat saleTransactionFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(SaleTransaction.class);

        //@formatter:off
        from(QueueNames.SALETRANSACTION_REQUESTS_QUEUE)
                .routeId("SaleTransactionRoute")
                .unmarshal(saleTransactionFormat)
                .beanRef("saleTransactionTransformer", "prepareSaleTransactionRequest")
                .end()
                .setHeader("operationName", constant("Create_Sales_Order_OB_SI"))
                .setHeader("SOAPAction", constant("http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1"))
                .doTry()
                .process(e->{
                    log.debug(e.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                    producer.sendBody(e.getIn().getBody());
                })
                .process(e->{
                    log.debug(e.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                    MessageContentsList contents = e.getIn().getBody(MessageContentsList.class);
                })
                    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "TMR Webservice has just been called successfully.")
                .doCatch(Exception.class)
                    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "TMR Webservice threw exception");
         //@formatter:on

    }
}
```

The cxf.xml file is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="tmrSaleTransactionService" address="{{tmr.saletransaction.uri}}"
                     wsdlURL="META-INF/wsdl/TmrSaleTransaction.wsdl"
                     serviceClass="au.gov.qld.qss.tmr_appl.albert.CreateSalesOrderOBSI">

        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="faultOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
</beans>
```

The application.properties file is as follows:

```
server.port=8084

# TMR Services URI
tmr.saletransaction.uri=https://sampleEndpointAddress

# Camel routes
camel.rouge.uri.jms.saletransaction.requests=activemq:queue:saletransaction:requests

# CXF URIs
camel.route.uri.tmrSaleTransactionWS=cxf:bean:tmrSaleTransactionService

##########################
# ActiveMQ Configuration #
##########################
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://ip-address:61616
spring.activemq.pooled=true
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=password

# Logging Level
#logging.level.*=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

The Application class is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {VelocityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml")
public class TmrServicesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TmrServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "loggingInInterceptor")
    public LoggingInInterceptor loggingInInterceptor() {
        return new LoggingInInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
                super.handleMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean(name = "loggingOutInterceptor")
    public LoggingOutInterceptor loggingOutInterceptor() {
        return new LoggingOutInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
                super.handleMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean(name = "faultOutInterceptor")
    public FaultOutInterceptor fault() {
        return new FaultOutInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
                super.handleMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When any request gets from the queue by camel, it cannot be submitted successfully to the Soap Webservice and the camel route log is as follows:

```
Could not find endpoint/port for {urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:Albert}Create_Sales_Order_OB_SIPort in wsdl. Using {urn:qss.qld.gov.au:TMR_APPL:Albert}HTTPS_Port.
```

Apart from that when I change the endpoint address in the application.properties file, no changes happened in the behavior.

**I think that something in the cxf.xml file has not been configured properly but I don't know what.**

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this one? If so, I'd be interested. Could you answer your own question?